# Responsive Layout Issue: Having 2 elements side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the Addpipe recorder service for a project and I want to have it next to an embedded video on Desktop. I'm using media queries to make the website responsive and on phone screens, I want the recorder to break into the next line. At all times I want everything to be centered. Here is the link to the project: https://fewnew.github.io/YNWA-web/

I've tried separating the recorder and embedded video into two columns on one row. It looks okay on phone size but not on desktop. Piperecorder takes an inline height and width value. I set the values to percentages but it doesn't seem to be affected. I'm a beginner web designer, and I would appreciate any help with this layout I'm trying to create. Thanks!

The HTML code:

```
<div class="row">

  <iframe class="half column" id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/251551404" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <!-- begin video recorder code -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.addpipe.com/2.0/pipe.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.addpipe.com/2.0/pipe.js"></script>

  <piperecorder class="half column" id="custom-id" pipe-width="100%" pipe-height="280" pipe-qualityurl="avq/288p.xml" pipe-accountHash="22864bed1e4827f6798d501706aeb89f" pipe-eid="1" pipe-mrt="120" ></piperecorder>

  <!-- end video recorder code -->

</div>
```

---

The CSS code:

```
/* Mobile first styles go here */

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    margin, padding:0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;

.container {
    width:80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row::before,
.row::after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}

.one,
.one-third,
.two-thirds,
.one-fourth,
.half {
    width: 100%;
}

#video {
    width:100%;
    height:280px;
    margin-top:6vh;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#custom-id {
    margin-top:6vh;
}

/* Desktop styles go here */

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

  .one {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .half {
        width: calc(100% / 2);
    }
    .one-third {
        width: calc(100% / 3);
    }
    .one-fourth {
        width: calc(100% / 4);
    }
    .two-thirds {
        width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
    }
    .column {
        float: left;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try flex box that will help you achieve your goal easily additionally if you expect your project to grow larger the future I would suggest you to invest the time in a css framework like bootstrap or materialize css or tailwind css

Answer (score 0):

So I will suggest you move these 2 lines to the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.addpipe.com/2.0/pipe.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src = "https://cdn.addpipe.com/2.0/pipe.js"></script>
```

then we are left with below

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="half-column">
        <iframe class="iframe"  id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video. /251551404" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>

  <div class="half-column">
        <piperecorder class="piperecorder" id="custom-id"  pipe-accountHash="22864bed1e4827f6798d501706aeb89f" pipe-eid="1" pipe-mrt="120" ></piperecorder>
   </div>

</div>
```

and the styles

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.half-column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.iframe {
  height: 270px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {

  .row {
     flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Hi Nana, thanks for your response. I made the edits you suggested, but it seems like the Addpipe recorder is mostly being problematic with the responsive layout since it takes inline values for height and width. It used to have a bright gray box which has now disappeared. Do you have any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: Here's a link to what it looks like now: https://fewnew.github.io/YNWA-web/index.html

Comment: I updated the solution. To keep a good aspect ratio and resolution, `pipe` has fixed width to 320px. So I centered that for a better look.

Comment: Hi Nana, I tried it with your updated solution. Its now centered onto the right side div, but it seems like the piperecorder's width somehow gets set to zero. When I click on record, the video recorder is no longer showing up.

Comment: Is it possible to have it set to a certain pixel value width on desktop size but scalable on smaller than 800px screen width?